# Referencing local files from HTML in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, local, relative-path

I have a very simple HTML app with uses a couple of js files, a css and several images. I have all of them bundled on a folder that I downloaded to my mobile phone in the Downloads folder.

Now, when I go to the folder and open the main html file, it opens in Chrome browser in the following url: content://media/external/file/<10 digit number> and no other file, locally referenced from it, loads. This means there are no images, and of course, no js functionality.

Where should I place my files, or how should I reference them from the main html file, to achieve a normal course of operation, where those files are normally loaded when executing main HTML file?

I know that I could download a small web server to run it locally and make it serve the page, but that seems quite overkill to me and I'd like to left that as a very last resort option.

Comment: have you tried with absolute, relative paths or `file://` protocol ?

Comment: @AfzalK. I've tried accessing also with file:// and file:///, but the html doesn't load this way. I have relative paths on my html file, I'd put absolute paths, but I don't know exactly to where I have to put them as the url in the browser changes when I open the file.

Comment: you can check that in details of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of those who might be on a similar situation, there is a MUCH BETTER approach to run your html + js + css apps on mobile devices.

You just need to convert them to Proggressive Web Applications (PWA), this means just to tweak them lightly and add a manifest file. Those apps CAN be INSTALLED on mobile devices directly from browsers, working as native apps.

You can find info about this topic in https://web.dev/explore/progressive-web-apps?hl=es-419

Answer (score 0):

You placed your files in a suitable folder.

The problem is that you used a content scheme uri that also hides real file names.

> content://media/external/file/123456

points to your html file. If the browser has to display a picture like image.jpg it will build an uri like content://media/external/file/image.jpg.

But that is no valid uri as this provider uses digits like you told us. And even if the url was ok you would not have read permission for it.

Comment: Is there any workaround to fix this?

Comment: It seems you have no Android app at all. Only a folder with some html files and such. Right?

Comment: exactly, plain vanilla html with js

Comment: Your html with relative paths is ok. Install a simple webserver like SimpleHttpServer. It goes for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission so it has all files access and can browse to your folder. It is no overkill at all.